# BigQuery - How to execute this php program?

Tags: php, google-bigquery

I am using a unix OS and I an trying to run [this](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/php-docs-samples/blob/master/bigquery/api/src/functions/run_query.php) program through the chrome browser.

To test the program I've added this line:

`run_query(/*project id*/, 'SELECT id, view_count FROM bigquery-public-data.stackoverflow.posts_questions WHERE tags like \'%google-bigquery%\' ORDER BY view_count DESC', false);`

I am sure that BigQuery has been installed properly and I have made a proper connection to the GCP because I can run the same query in command line and it returns correct results.

I am pretty sure that the issue lays with line 44 since that's where the program breaks. With that in mind I have made sure that the projectID string is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I figured out the issue. So Apache uses a different permission structure when running php programs. So when I was trying to run the program through the browser Apache would check the service account key json file and be denied access because I hadn't specifically given it read permissions.

Once I accounted for that it worked fine.